# Sweet.js - How to put variable in identifier name and string variable?

Tags: javascript, macros, sweet.js

I'm brand new to Sweet.js. My first simple macro is the following

```
macro test {
  rule {
    $className($entityName)
  } => {
    function test$className()
    {
      console.print("$className");
      console.print("$entityName");
    }
  }
}

test me(More)
```

which produces

```
function test$className() {
    console.print(me);
    console.print(More);
}
```

but I'd like it to produce this:

```
function testMe() {
    console.print("me");
    console.print("More");
}
```

but any variants I've tried for it haven't worked. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use a case macro to construct the exact tokens you want:

```
macro test {
    case {_
        $className($entityName)
    } => {
        var classStr = unwrapSyntax(#{$className}[0]);
        var entityStr = unwrapSyntax(#{$entityName}[0]);
        letstx $fnName = [makeIdent("test" + classStr, #{here})];
        letstx $classStr = [makeValue(classStr, #{here})];
        letstx $entityStr = [makeValue(entityStr, #{here})];
        return #{
            function $fnName()
            {
                console.print($classStr);
                console.print($entityStr);
            }
        }
    }
}

test me(More)
```